# Nginx "direct_io" and "sendfile" effect

Tags: nginx, static-files, sendfile, aio

How can see the effect of direct_io and sendfile directive on my server? I want to compare with this settings and without. Is there any tool for do it?

```
sendfile on;
aio on;
directio 512k;
```

Thanks.

Comment: it's not a bad question, but this question isn't about programming and isn't suited for stackoverflow.com. try https://serverfault.com - i have voted to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I wrote to serverfault.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use JMeter load test tool, copy many video files in your web app (nginx server)

and start using Jmeter with 1000 users requests to those files using HTTP Request Sampler in JMeter